# Counting How Many Times a "Peak" Happens

Tags: excel

I'm in excel trying to count how many "peaks" there are in my data.  Initially I thought "find the median, set a threshold value, count the number of values above said threshold value."  So I ended up using =median(),=max() and =ifcount().

The problem is is that for a peak, there may be data-points that end up making the "slope" of said peak which are higher than the threshold value.

Wondering if there's an easy way in excel to count said peaks, or if I have to figure out a way to convert the data to a function and take a second derivative to find local maxima points.

Comment: Have you considered setting a condition that the previous and next values must both be less than the value in question in order for it to be designated a peak?

Comment: An example of what you have, what you've tried, and what you're trying to do, would be helpful.